# PyFlink on Kinesis Analytics Studio - Cannot convert DataStream to Amazon Kinesis Data Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis, pyflink

I have a DataStream `<pyflink.datastream.data_stream.DataStream>` coming from a CoFlatMapFunction (simplified here):

```py
%flink.pyflink
# join two streams and update the rule-set
class MyCoFlatMapFunction(CoFlatMapFunction):

    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        state_desc = MapStateDescriptor('map', Types.STRING(), Types.BOOLEAN())
        self.state = runtime_context.get_map_state(state_desc)

    def bool_from_user_number(self, user_number: int):
        '''Retunrs True if user_number is greater than 0, False otherwise.'''
        if user_number > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def flat_map1(self, value):
        '''This method is called for each element in the first of the connected streams'''
        self.state.put(value[1], self.bool_from_user_number(value[2]))

    def flat_map2(self, value):
        '''This method is called for each element in the second of the connected streams (exchange_server_tickers_data_py)'''

        current_dateTime = datetime.now()
        dt = current_dateTime

        x = value[1]
        y = value[2]

        yield Row(dt, x, y)

def generate__ds(st_env):
    # interpret the updating Tables as DataStreams
    type_info1 = Types.ROW([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])
    ds1 = st_env.to_append_stream(table_1 , type_info=type_info1)

    type_info2 = Types.ROW([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])
    ds2 = st_env.to_append_stream(table_2 , type_info=type_info2)

    output_type_info = Types.ROW([ Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY() ,Types.STRING(),Types.STRING() ])
    # Connect the two streams
    connected_ds = ds1.connect(ds2)
    # Apply the CoFlatMapFunction
    ds = connected_ds.key_by(lambda a: a[0], lambda a: a[0]).flat_map(MyCoFlatMapFunction(), output_type_info)
    return ds

ds = generate__ds(st_env)
```

The output, however, I am unable to view, either via registering it as a view / table, writing to a sink table or (the best case) using a Kinesis Streams sink to write data from the Flink stream into a Kinesis stream. Firehouse would also not fit my use case as the 30 second latency would be too long. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

### What I have tried:

Registering it as a view / table like so:

```py
# interpret the DataStream as a Table
input_table = st_env.from_data_stream(ds).alias("dt", "x", "y")
z.show(input_table, stream_type="update")
```

Which gives an error of:

```
Query schema: [dt: RAW('[B', '...'), x: STRING, y: STRING]
Sink schema:  [dt: RAW('[B', ?), x: STRING, y: STRING]
```

I have also tried writing to a sink table, like so:

```py
%flink.pyflink
# create a sink table to emit results
st_env.execute_sql("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_sink""")

st_env.execute_sql("""
    CREATE TABLE table_sink (
        dt RAW('[B', '...'),
        x VARCHAR(32),
        y STRING
    ) WITH (
        'connector' = 'print'
    )
""")

# convert the Table API table to a SQL view
table = st_env.from_data_stream(ds).alias("dt", "spread", "spread_orderbook")
st_env.execute_sql("""DROP TEMPORARY VIEW IF EXISTS table_api_table""")
st_env.create_temporary_view('table_api_table', table)

# emit the Table API table
st_env.execute_sql("INSERT INTO table_sink SELECT * FROM table_api_table").wait()
```

I get the error:
 `org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to restore the RAW type of class '[B' with serializer snapshot '...'.`

I have also tried to use a sink and `add_sink` to write the data to a sink, which would be an AWS kinesis data stream like in these [Docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/datastream/kinesis/), like so:

```py
%flink.pyflink
from pyflink.common.serialization import JsonRowSerializationSchema
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import KinesisStreamsSink

output_type_info = Types.ROW([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])
serialization_schema = JsonRowSerializationSchema.Builder().with_type_info(output_type_info).build()

# Required
sink_properties = {
    'aws.region': 'eu-west-2'
}

kds_sink = KinesisStreamsSink.builder()
            .set_kinesis_client_properties(sink_properties)
            .set_serialization_schema(SimpleStringSchema())
            .set_partition_key_generator(PartitionKeyGenerator
            .fixed())
            .set_stream_name("test_stream")
            .set_fail_on_error(False)
            .set_max_batch_size(500)
            .set_max_in_flight_requests(50)
            .set_max_buffered_requests(10000)
            .set_max_batch_size_in_bytes(5 * 1024 * 1024)
            .set_max_time_in_buffer_ms(5000)
            .set_max_record_size_in_bytes(1 * 1024 * 1024)
            .build()

ds.sink_to(kds_sink)
```

Which i assume would work, but KinesisStreamsSink is not found in `pyflink.datastream.connectors` and I am unable to find any documentation on how to do this within AWS Kinesis Analytics Studio. Any help would be much much appreciated, thank you! How would I go about writing the data to a Kinesis Streams sink / converting it to a table?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i have figured it out. There were a couple issues with the particular Pyflink version available on AWS Kinesis Analytics Studio (1.13). The error messages themselves were not that useful, so for anyone who is having issues themselves I would really recommend viewing the errors in the Flink Web UI. Firstly, the `MapStateDescriptor` datatypes must be specified using `Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY()`. Secondly, not shown in the Qn, but each `MapStateDescriptor` must have a distinct name. I also found that using `Row` from `pyflink.common` threw errors for me. It worked better for me to switch to using use Tuples by specifying `Types.TUPLE()` as is done in [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/api/python//examples/datastream/timer.html) example. I also had to switch to specifying the output as a tuple.

Another thing I have not done is specify a watermark strategy for the DataStream, which could potentially be done by extracting the timestamp from the first field, and assign watermarks based on knowledge of the stream:

```py
class MyTimestampAssigner(TimestampAssigner):
    def extract_timestamp(self, value, record_timestamp: int) -> int:
        return int(value[0])

watermark_strategy = WatermarkStrategy.for_bounded_out_of_orderness(Duration.of_seconds(5)).with_timestamp_assigner(MyTimestampAssigner())
ds = ds.assign_timestamps_and_watermarks(watermark_strategy)

# the first field has been used for timestamp extraction, and is no longer necessary
# replace first field with a logical event time attribute
table = st_env.from_data_stream(ds, col("dt").rowtime, col('f0'), col('f1'))
```

But i have instead created a sink table for writing to a Kinesis Data Stream again as an output. In total, the corrected code would look something like this:

```py
from pyflink.table.expressions import col
from pyflink.datastream.state import MapStateDescriptor
from pyflink.datastream.functions import RuntimeContext, CoFlatMapFunction
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.common import Duration as Time, WatermarkStrategy, Duration
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.common.watermark_strategy import TimestampAssigner
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.functions import KeyedProcessFunction, RuntimeContext
from pyflink.datastream.state import ValueStateDescriptor
from datetime import datetime 

# Register the tables in the env
table1 = st_env.from_path("sql_table_1")
table2 = st_env.from_path("sql_table_2")

# interpret the updating Tables as DataStreams
type_info1 = Types.TUPLE([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])
ds1 = st_env.to_append_stream(table2, type_info=type_info1)

type_info2 = Types.TUPLE([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])
ds2 = st_env.to_append_stream(table1, type_info=type_info2)

# join two streams and update the rule-set state
class MyCoFlatMapFunction(CoFlatMapFunction):
    
    def open(self, runtime_context: RuntimeContext):
        '''This method is called when the function is opened in the runtime. It is the initialization purposes.'''
        # Map state that we use to maintain the filtering and rules
        state_desc = MapStateDescriptor('map', Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY(), Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY())
        self.state = runtime_context.get_map_state(state_desc)
        
        # maintain state 2
        ob_state_desc = MapStateDescriptor('map_OB', Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY(), Types.PICKLED_BYTE_ARRAY())
        self.ob_state = runtime_context.get_map_state(ob_state_desc)
                   
    # called on ds1
    def flat_map1(self, value):
        '''This method is called for each element in the first of the connected streams '''
        list_res = value[1].split('|')
        for i in list_res:
            time = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
            yield (time, f"{i}_one")

    # called on ds2
    def flat_map2(self, value):
        '''This method is called for each element in the second of the connected streams'''
        list_res = value[1].split('|')
        for i in list_res:
            time = datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
            yield (time, f"{i}_two")
        
connectedStreams = ds1.connect(ds2)
output_type_info = Types.TUPLE([Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP(), Types.STRING()])
ds = connectedStreams.key_by(lambda value: value[1], lambda value: value[1]).flat_map(MyCoFlatMapFunction(), output_type=output_type_info)


name = 'output_table'
ds_table_name = 'temporary_table_dump'

st_env.execute_sql(f"""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {name}""")

def create_table(table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos):
    return """ CREATE TABLE {0} (
                f0 TIMESTAMP(3),
                f1 STRING,
                WATERMARK FOR f0 AS f0 - INTERVAL '5' SECOND
              )
              WITH (
                'connector' = 'kinesis',
                'stream' = '{1}',
                'aws.region' = '{2}',
                'scan.stream.initpos' = '{3}',
                'sink.partitioner-field-delimiter' = ';',
                'sink.producer.collection-max-count' = '100',
                'format' = 'json',
                'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601'
              ) """.format(
        table_name, stream_name, region, stream_initpos
    )

# Creates a sink table writing to a Kinesis Data Stream
st_env.execute_sql(create_table(name, 'output-test', 'eu-west-2', 'LATEST'))
table = st_env.from_data_stream(ds)
st_env.execute_sql(f"""DROP TEMPORARY VIEW IF EXISTS {ds_table_name}""")
st_env.create_temporary_view(ds_table_name, table)

# emit the Table API table 
st_env.execute_sql(f"INSERT INTO {name} SELECT * FROM {ds_table_name}").wait()
```